# hover() jquery only work on first item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my js like this

```
$('#link').hover(function(){
                $(this).find('.actionBlck').css('opacity','0.85');
            },function(){
                $(this).find('.actionBlck').css('opacity','1');
            });

        });
```

and I have html like `<a id='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>` within a foreach loop. It work but only the first item will got the effect, why? I inspect my html, it has multiple link id.

Comment: you cannot use multiple items with the same `id`, it is invalid HTML. that is why it only chooses the first element with that `id`, because it is supposed to be unique and jQuery stops looking for any others. try using a class instead.

Comment: "it has multiple link id" - this is the problem. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 3):

`id`s are meant to be unique. You can only have ONE element with a certain `id` on a page. Classes, though, can be duplicated. Classes are meant to provide clustering and grouping of common elements. Ids are menat to select a single element.

```
    $('.link').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.actionBlck').css('opacity','0.85');
        },function(){
            $(this).find('.actionBlck').css('opacity','1');
        });

    });
```

With html like `<a class='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting by id. Id's are supposed to be unique. Therefore when you select by id jquery will *only ever return one element*.

So if you have this:

```
<a id='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>...</a>
<a id='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>...</a>
```

And then you select like this:

```
$('#link').hover(function(){
    // do something
}
```

It will *only ever* attach the handler to the first item.

Use a class instead:

```
<a class='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>...</a>
<a class='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>...</a>
```

And then attach a handler like so:

```
$('.link').hover(function(){
    // do something
}
```

When you use an id selector (`#`) in jquery it will be translated into a call to the DOM function `getElementById`. Note that it's get "element" not get "elements" and it only ever returns a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Because the ID attribute is a **unique** identifier. Meaning that multiple elements cannot have the same id.

Use a class instead, like so:

`<a class='link' href=".$link." target='_blank'>`

and change the jQuery selector to `$('.link')`